# How do I download flutter packages to use it if I was offline?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wonder if there is a way to download ***flutter***  packages for **offline** using please , so that I can use it always in my flutter projects when I was offline , I don't want to always add the package in pubspec.yaml and pubget , always needs a wifi connection , I want it to download it for once and use it always like a bootstrap , or jquery download files compiled codes ,, I think it can be a little boring for all of the developers that use a package for hundred times and download it awlays and always

Comment: when you run `pub get` while online, the package get's saved to your computer so ideally you can still use package while offline

Comment: yes I know that bro ,  but i want to download the package for once and use it for many of my projects , I want to add to pubspec to the rest of the projects without having wifi connection , i dont want to always have a wifi connection for anyone of my project to get this package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to add a dependency like this

```
dependencies:
  flutter_dependency:
    git:
      url: local-git-repo-previously-cheched-out
```

Comment: sorry i didnt get it bro ,

Comment: yes I know that bro , but i want to download the package for once and use it for many of my projects , I want to add to pubspec to the rest of the projects without having wifi connection , i dont want to always have a wifi connection for anyone of my project to get this package –

Comment: you just need to download it the first time, after the first time your package is cached locally in the.    `.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/plugin` folder

Comment: also since android builds are performed by Gradle use `gradle --offline build` when you are online to be sure Gradle downloads all dependencies